# Opening window with Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I open a new window using the vue router, but the opened window cannot access the data of the main application. In other words, the vue store state has initialisation values. Is it possible to open such a window, but for it to access the vue store data.

```
openMonitor() {
    let routeData = this.$router.resolve({name: 'Monitor'});
    window.open(routeData.href, '_blank', "width=1500,height=600,left=200,top=200");
},
```

Comment: You cannot do this directly, these are different apps in different windows at this point. Exchange data with main app through localStorage or window messages.

Comment: Why you don't use `this.$router.push()`

Comment: @EstusFlask which method will be more efficient? I have to exchange data every 0.5 second, because I'm fetching some realtime values from API.

Comment: @RaphaelRollet I need to open this route in new window

Comment: Can't say, both about efficiency, but messages are more straightforward, they just solve the task. Can't post the specific code but there should be window.opener.postMessage to request info inside a popup, and then popup.postMessage to send it there